# Digital signature appearance.setContact not showing

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature

Having a problem with `appearance.setContact(String);` method.
I can sign a pdf document with my app, using itext (java) but for some reason my signature is not showing Contact info and I don't have i clue why is that.

appearance.setReason();
appearance.setLocation();

are working just fine, my sign method is passing three strings for Reason, Location and Contact but for some reason Contact is not showing???

and everything is set up correctly.

```
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setReason(reason);
        appearance.setLocation(location);
        appearance.setContact(contact);
        appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(50, 700, 150, 800), 1, "sig");
        appearance.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);
```

does anyone have a clue?!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a digital signature, you "fill out" a signature field of which the `/V` entry refers to a signature dictionary. This signature dictionary contains a number of entries, among which the reason, location and contact info.

When you use the `setReason()`, `setLocation()` and `setContact()` methods, these entries are filled out correctly. Regarding the `/ContactInfo` key, the draft of ISO-32000-2 defines it like this:

> **ContactInfo** Information provided by the signer to enable a recipient to contact
>   the signer to verify the signature. If SubFilter is ETSI.RFC3161, this
>   entry should not be used and should be ignored by a interactive PDF
>   processor. EXAMPLE: A phone number.

This is one aspect of your question: you can be 100% sure that iText creates these entries correctly.

The second aspect of your question involves the visual appearance of a signature, more specifically the appearance of the widget annotation of the signature.

You can create this appearance any way you want to (see section 2.4.2 of [my book about digital signatures](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures)), but for your convenience, iText can also create an appearance that takes the name that is mentioned in the certificate, along with the location and the reason for signing. That was a design choice. We didn't think it would be important to show a phone number in the signature.

The reason why the contact is not showing is that we didn't think it made sense to show it. If you *do* want to show it (for instance because it's part of your requirements), you should have no problem creating the appearance using custom code.

Comment: app.sign(SRC, DEST, chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, providerMSCAPI.getName(), CryptoStandard.CMS, "Reason", "Location","Contact",null, null, null, 0);
in combination with: PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setReason(reason);
        appearance.setLocation(location);
        appearance.setContact(contact); is not working, so you are saying I should use setLayer2Text(); did i got it wright? thanks Bruno

Comment: i tried using setLayer2Text() and it overrides the setReason() and setLocation() would like to make setContact() show it self. @BrunoLowagie

Comment: I am saying that you should create the **complete** appearance yourself, instead of saying that the *convenience* methods aren't working. The *convenience* methods are *for your convenience*. It is *unfair* to say that they don't work, just because they don't meet your unusual requirement. If you have an unusual requirement, you need to implement that requirement.